# Why make grouping in ascending or descending order in Table Data not show properly smaller to greater than

Tags: uitableview

Ascending and Descending Making Groups

Why Java Table not showing properly greater to smaller than or smaller to greater than values

[image]

Comment: You're sorting it as text? That's alphabetical order

Comment: no I am sorting as integer value

Comment: use this line for sorting tbl_reports.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true). colum have integer value but that make group wise sorting